# Confused with Auto Layout in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, autolayout

I am making the layout of my app comparable with 3.5 inch devices. However, I am confused with Constraints and Auto Layout.

I am trying to make a view always be in the center of two views regardless of the screen size but whenever I do this it always goes behind another view.

The 4 inch view:

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/41qQl.png]

The 3.5 inch view:

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/6PFSx.png (t)]

If someone could help me figure out why this is happening I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Constraints should be like this

I(any y value you want your UILabel to start at)

I(+30)
UILabel (Safe)
I(+30)
UITExtField
I(+30)
UIView that contains all Number Buttons.

Adjust all accurately that it work in least possible dimensions. i-e 3.5

Answer (score 1):

You can add a wrapper view (normal UIView is okay), align the top bound with the bottom of "safe", align the bottom bound with the top of the circle. Two constraints should be added automatically. Then put your inner view at the vertical center of the wrapper view.

Comment: When you say wrapper view do you mean container view?

Comment: a normal UIView is okay.